# How do I inject IHttpClientFactory in my Azure Service Fabric application?

Tags: c#, autofac, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to use `IHttpClientFactory` in my solution instead of just instances of `HttpClient`.

startup.cs:

```
services.AddHttpClient("Test", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57863");
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
});
```

and in my services in need of a HttpClient:

```
private readonly Uri _clusterLinuxUri;
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
public LiasseService(ConfigSettings settings, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
    _clusterLinuxUri = new Uri($"{settings.LinuxClusterEndpoint}");
    _clientFactory = clientFactory;
}
public async Task<LiasseDetails> CreateLiasseAsync(LiasseCreate liasseData)
{
    using (var response = await _clientFactory.CreateClient("Test")
        .PostAsJsonAsync($"{_clusterLinuxUri}{_createPath}", liasseData))
    {
        await response.CheckHttpError($"{nameof(CreateLiasseAsync)} - error in CL");
        var detailsList = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<LiasseDetailsList>();
        return detailsList.Details.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

The part I haven't figured out is how to inject it in Autofac.

program.cs

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterModule(new GlobalAutofacModule());
            builder.RegisterServiceFabricSupport();
            builder.RegisterStatelessService<FacadeCore>("xxx.FacadeCoreType");

            using (builder.Build())
            {
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceTypeRegistered(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, typeof(FacadeCore).Name);
                Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceHostInitializationFailed(e.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }


    public class GlobalAutofacModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<ConfigSettings>();

            builder.RegisterType<PaymentService>().As<IPaymentService>();
            builder.RegisterType<MailerService>().As<IMailerService>();
            builder.RegisterType<LiasseService>().As<ILiasseService>();
            builder.RegisterType<AnalyseFinanciereService>().As<IAnalyseFinanciereService>();
            builder.RegisterType<ApimService>().As<IApimService>();

            builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>();
            builder.RegisterType<ApplicationProcessRepository>().As<IApplicationProcessRepository>();
            builder.RegisterType<LiasseRepository>().As<ILiasseRepository>();

            builder.RegisterType<CustomUserIdProvider>().As<IUserIdProvider>();
        }
    }
```

Am I supposed to create some custom client that implements `IHttpClientFactory` to be able to inject it? How should I do this? Any examples? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Please see [Interface documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.ihttpclientfactory?view=aspnetcore-2.2) here

So to answer your question:

1) Using `IServiceCollection` from 'ConfigureServices' method call  `.AddHttpClient()`

2) Create new Autofac container builder and populate it with `IServiceCollection` mentioned above

3) From `ConfigureServices` method return new `AutofacServiceProvider`

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...

   services.AddHttpClient();

   var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

   containerBuilder.Populate(services);

   var container = containerBuilder.Build();

   return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}
```

P.S.
Make sure to add - Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection nuget package, in order to be able to use `AutofacServiceProvider` class.

Comment: unfortunately I'm in the context of a service fabric, the containerbuilder is in the program.cs of my api while the configureservices is in my startup.cs

Comment: probably my first try long ago and probably didn't work as I usually try the simplest first, I don't remember though ;)

Comment: As far as i understand FacadeCore is the stateless or may be statefull service where you use a webhostBuilder and register the startup class.
My suggestion is to move all kind of dependencies registration logic to the "Startup" class.
All this kind of SF related stuff is just to get your service running, and the "startup" as stupid as it may sound is to startup(prepare) your application :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from doing using a `WebHostBuilder` based solution similar to what you get when creating a vanilla Asp.Net Core Service Fabric project, you can alternatively just do this

```
public class HttpClientModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        
        builder.Register(_ =>
            {
                var services = new ServiceCollection();
                services.AddHttpClient();
                var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
                containerBuilder.Populate(services);
                var container = containerBuilder.Build();
                return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
            })
            .As<IServiceProvider>()
            .SingleInstance();


        builder.Register(ctx =>
        {
            var scope = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
            var provider = scope.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
            var factory = provider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            return factory.CreateClient();
        }).As<HttpClient>();
    }
}
```